# How to make ADO parameter to update SQL Server datetime column?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

**edit** I should have mentioned that I'm trying to do this with Delphi 2006.

OK, I think I have hit on a question with no previous answers.

I have a SQL Server database with columns of type `datetime`. When I try to insert a row with a parametrized command, I get

```
Exception class EOleException with message
'[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented'.
```

My insert procedure looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnZoomClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  InsCmd = 'insert into dbo.foo (added, edited, editor, narrative) ' +
           'values (:dateAdded, :dateEdited, :theEditor, :theNarrative);';
begin
  dmDbToy2.DataModule2.ADOCommand1.CommandText := InsCmd;
  with DataModule2.ADOCommand1.Parameters do
  begin
// the following line was an attempt to trick VarAsType into making a
// adDbTimeStamp: VarAsType is having none of it.
//    FindParam('dateAdded').Value := VarAsType(VarFromDateTime(Now), 135);
    FindParam('dateAdded').Value := VarFromDateTime(Now);
    FindParam('dateEdited').Value := Null;
    FindParam('theEditor').Value := 'wades';
    FindParam('theNarrative').Value := Null;
  end;
  DataModule2.ADOCommand1.Execute;
end;
```

I found some postings via [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=addbtimestamp+datetime&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=RY9JTazEE4qtgQeP9Pk-&start=0&sa=N) which seem to indicate that SQL Server wants a `adDbTimeStamp` type to update these columns, but VarAsType does not want to make one for me.

Is there a way to create a value for the `dateAdded` and `dateEdited` parameters in the code sample?

Comment: Have you tried using `FindParam('dateAdded').AsDate := Now;`? (Could be AsDateTime, working from memory here)

Comment: That approach raises `EVariantInvalidOpError` with message 'Invalid variant operation'.

Comment: wades, maybe the problem is the provider which you are using. show your connection string to see the current provider used by your app.

Comment: `Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=FBCS\SQLEXPRESS;UID=Wades;APP=Professional;WSID=FBCS;DATABASE=wades-test0;Trusted_Connection=Yes";Initial Catalog=wades-test0`

Comment: you are using the `OLEDB Provider for ODBC` try instead using the `OLEDB provider for Sql Server` the connection string is like this `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=user_password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user_name;Initial Catalog=database_name;Data Source=server_name`

Comment: @RRUZ - You think this approach will work with _e.g._ `Value := Variant(Now);` ?

Comment: @wades, some time ago i have a similar issue with the odbc driver and a `datetime` field. when i change the provider all works ok. about your  question try using `ParamByName('dateAdded').AsDateTime := now;` as @jachguate suggest.

Comment: What data type is the fields in your db and what data type is ADOCommand1? I assumed in my answer that it is TADOCommand but you have commented here that you have tried `FindParam('dateAdded').AsDate := Now;`. I can not see how that is possible using TADOCommand. On the other hand it is quite late so I might be misstaken.

Comment: @RRUZ - I think you should enter an answer with the suggestion to change to the SQLOLEDB.1 provider so that I can mark this one answered.

Comment: @wades, changing the provider solved your problem?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: The data field is type `datetime` as mentioned in the OP. `ADOCommand1` is in fact `TADOCommand`. I do not understand why people are suggesting I assign to `AsDateTime` because that leads to an immediate exception in the assignment statement.

Comment: @RRUZ, yes, it solved the problem that I was not able to update/insert/query `datetime` columns using a parameter. I have some other issues too but those were not the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @wades - Yes that was strange. Even if you got your issue straight I think you should take as practice to use ParamByName and specify the datatype of the parameter. I do not recall right now the problems I had with not doing that but there where some cases calling stored procs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments thread on the original question, user RRUZ made a suggestion that turned out to resolve the issue: The problem was with the provider. Namely, I was using the `OLEDB Provider for ODBC` rather than the `OLEDB Provider for SQL Server`. Changing the provider as suggested made the `'Optional feature not implemented'` error message go away and enabled the  insert to work with a simple assignment of `TDateTime` to `TParameter.Value`, thusly:

```
FindParam('dateAdded').Value := Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the parameter as a datetime.  I do it all the time in ADO and other conection layers

```
DataModule2.ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('dateAdded').Value := Now();
//other code
DataModule2.ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('dateEdited').Value := Null;
//other code
DataModule2.AdoCommand1.Execute;
```

Comment: This also raises `EVariantInvalidOpError` with message 'Invalid variant operation'.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `.Clear` method of TParameter? I use D2010 and do not see it.

Comment: TParam in db.pas has both AsDateTime and Clear, TParameter in ADODB.pas does not. The name ADOCommand1 suggests that it is TADOCommand object that OP is using.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: It's not `TParamater.Clear` or `TParamater.AsDateTime`, it's `System.Variant.Clear` etc.

Comment: @Mickael you're right, I tried right now with XE/ADOQuery and there's no such methods I use with other components.  I updated my answer to show the correct ones.

Comment: +1 I have made extensive use of parameterised TADOQuerys with SQL Server datetime types, and never done *anything* other than `ParamByName('DateParam').Value := aTDateTime`.

Comment: Ignore previous, I always use TADOQuery rather than TADOCommand. That been said, I have written a test query using TADOCommand, and this worked OK. One thing to check is that ADOCommand1 is correctly "wired up" to an open TADOConnection, as this is required for it to parse parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Set the datatype for the parameter, it might do a difference in how the parameters is treated. I would also recommend that you use ParamByName instead of FindParam. With ParamByName you get a Param xx not found exception if the parameters does not exist in the Parameters collection. FindParam returns nil if it is not found. I have never needed to use any variant conversion stuff when assigning parameters for a TADOCommand so think you should remove that as well.

Try this.

```
    with ParamByName('dateAdded') do
    begin
        DataType := ftDateTime;
        Value := Now;
    end;

    with ParamByName('dateEdited') do
    begin
        DataType := ftDateTime;
        Value := Null;
    end;

    with ParamByName('theEditor') do
    begin
        DataType := ftString; // or ftWideString if you use nchar/nvarchar
        Value := 'wades';
    end;

    with ParamByName('theNarrative') do
    begin
        //DataType := ftString // Don't  know datatype here
        Value := Null;
    end;
```